# Extracting a table from Webpage in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried reading a table from a website. It can be seen from my code that I have gone too far to get the table, I would appreciate if someone give me an opportunity to learn a quick method to do the same.

### Here's my code:

```
    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    url = "http://www.kazusa.or.jp/codon/cgi-bin/showcodon.cgi?species=9606&aa=1&style=N"
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    text = soup.get_text()
    with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(text)
    with open('myfile.txt','r') as g:
        f = g.readlines()
    tab = f[12:31]
    table = [x.strip() for x in tab]
```

---

Every time running the code messes up with writing and reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need files. Filter for the `pre` tag instead, to target the table alone.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text=soup.find('pre')
table = [x.strip() for x in text]
```